# What is this foreign address called cartfill in windows netstat

Tags: windows, netstat

This is the result of netstat in my Winodws 8 CMD

```
C:\Windows\System32>netstat

Active Connections

Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
TCP    127.0.0.1:2311         cartfill:2312          ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:2312         cartfill:2311          ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.2.2:1053       bom04s02-in-f8:http    CLOSE_WAIT
```

The Local Address ports (2311, 2312) for this cartfill belongs to firefox. If i close firefox they will go away. Previously they used to open with Nvidea Sync processes. Suspecting I have unistalled them. Now they are with Firefox.

So far I know this cartfill is some ad website used to popup while watching sites with TV Episodes. Considering the name match i suspecting ti is some kind of adware. I have setup HOST file with this cartfill to loop back to 127 ip in local.

So any one got any idea. Nothing got much with in Google search particular to this point.

Comment: Are you claiming that you saw `cartfill` in your `netstat` output *before* you added it to your hosts file? Is there any other local resource that could have provided this name in the first place? (E.g., is it your host's *name*, or is it in your local DNS tables?)

Comment: @G-Man, as David Schwartz answered, it is showing up because i added it in the host and finally forgot about it after long time, then worried. Initially I blocked this cartfill in hosts. Yes as u asked I didn't know seeing it before adding it to host file. Only few days back noticed it. Once i removed it from the hosts it is not showing it up any more. :) my bad. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not really a foreign address. Those two connections are two ends of the same connection, and the connection is purely local. As you explained, "I have setup HOST file with this cartfill to loop back to 127 ip in local."

Comment: Does that explain both occurrences or just one?

Comment: @David, Yes i noticed they are having matching ports. So my main concern is "Why" the name "cartfill". What it could be? Or is it just because I setup the host. "127.0.0.1 cartfill.com/cartfill.in"

Comment: You put the name in the hosts file. Why are you asking us what it means?